# Data binding - getBindingContext() returns absolute path rather than relative

Tags: sapui5

I've got a table which I'm firing an event on row selection. In the handler I want to get the context for the selected row and then create a new context for a lower level oData object and then bind that to a Text view.

I'm sure there is a beautifully succinct way of doing this but currently I am:

Getting the binding path and adding a string to create a path to my lower level object:
    var path = oEvent.getParameters().listItem.getBindingContext().sPath + "/ComplianceNote";

This is returning a path with / as the first character, from what I understand this means it's the root object of the service or this is an "absolute" path. My current workaround is to remove the first character:

```
path = path.substr(1, path.length);
```

Then I can bind my Text view:

```
noteText.bindElement(path);
noteText.bindProperty("text", "Note");
```

This works fine but seems to me to be a code smell hacking around with the string. My questions are:

1. Why is the path returned as "absolute" rather than "relative"
2. What is the correct way to achieve this. I've been looking at things like setBindContext and bindText.

Cheers,
Gregor

Comment: OData or oData? bRelative = !jQuery.sap.startsWith(sPath, "/")) (!bRelative) this.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1)

Comment: OData, oops. Do you mean use a ternary operator to check the first char? i.e `var bRelative = !jQuery.sap.startsWith(path, "/") ? (path) : path.substr(1);`

Comment: yep - if you want to bind /Products(2)/Notes to your control, if it already has inherited or set a bindingContext of "/Products(2)" then the path would be relative eg "Notes" no slash, else for ODataModel you would need to set the fullpath "/Products(2)/Notes"

Comment: the doco on Binding Path Syntax   https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/ODataModel.html